# ExtJS Grid Cell locking + Editing results in exception

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a simple grid, in which I want to lock some cells. But if the cell editing plugin is also set, the i get the following error:

TypeError: view.selModel is undefined

My code is the following:

```
Ext.define('BT.view.EmployeeView', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.employeeview',

    store: 'Employees',

    header: false,

    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],

    columns: [
        {header: 'Employee', dataIndex: 'employee', locked: true, width: 200},
        {header: 'Bonus', dataIndex: 'bonus', flex:1, xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                allowBlank:true,
                store: 'Months',
                displayField: 'month',
                valueField: 'value',
            }
        }   
    ]
});
```

If I remove the plugins part, then there is no error, and locking works fine:

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    })
],
```

If there are no columns set with an editor, the problem is still the same. Somehow the plugins statement messes things up. Although if that array is empty there is no error again.
Why is this causing a problem, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think that you are seeing a bug that was fixed with the newly released version 4.2.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?165284-4.1-beta-Locking-grid-do-not-respond-to-cellclick-event&p=923643

Comment: Totally right, the error is no more in 4.2. Thanks for the hint!